# What is necessary for creating WP8 apps?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-7, windows-8.1

I've just got myself a WP8, and I want to start creating apps for it. The only thing that I need to know, is what kind of programs that are truly necessary for stating up. According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh986964.aspx), I need windows 8.1 for computer, but I don't have that. Do I *need* to upgrade my PC, or can I do the programming with windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 you can create apps for Windows Phone 7 platform. All apps for WP7 will run on every WP8 device (so, unless you need a specific funcionality available only for WP8, target WP7 for wider 'market'). All you need is Windows Phone SDK (7.1 version with updates). Download here: http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk